Why can't I build artifacts with IntelliJ using Random.nextFloat(min, max)?
I wrote a large code-base that extensively relies on the java.util.Random.nextFloat(min, max) function. I probably use the function a few dozen unique times in my program, and it works when I run the project in IntelliJ. The problem? I was building my project into an executable .jar, and I received the following error:
C:\Users\djack\Desktop\LibGdx Games\Space Game\core\src\main\java\org\origin\spacegame\entities\Planet.java:35:71
java: method nextFloat in class java.util.Random cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found:    float,float
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I can't really find a good reason why IntelliJ's code autocomplete feature offers the function as an option, and why it seems to run just fine in practice, but then doesn't recognize the function signature when building into an executable.
The only reason I can imagine is, Random.nextFloat(min, max) might not be available in all Java versions - and, if IntelliJ is building with a different Java version from the one it uses to run the project, then that could be the problem.

Which Java versions are you using to build/run/compile the project? Is it the same version everywhere?
